# Definir array por Index

Tags: php

Tengo una array multi con datos que incluyen  fechas, lo quiero hacer es pasar esos datos a otra array multi  pero ordenado  por  indice de mes, es decir, si tengo fecha 02/05/2017 en la otra array se tiene crear el index 5 y meter  alli meter todas las arrays con mes 5.

La array con los datos vienen de una consulta.

Este el codigo que tengo de mientras.

```
$result=[
            array("131","2017-05-24","2017-06-24","A","B","1","0","1"),
            array("132","2017-05-24","2017-06-10","C","D","0","1","0"),
            ];

$FArray=[];

            for ($i=0; $i<count($result);$i++){
                $NIMes=substr($result[$i][1],-5,5);
                $MesIN=substr($NIMes,1,2);
                $FIMes=substr($result[$i][2],-5,5);
                $MesFI=substr($FIMes,0,2);
                $MesI=(int)$MesIN;
                $MesF=(int)$MesFI;


                if (array_key_exists($MesI,$FArray)) {
                    array_push($FArray[$MesI],$result[$i]);
                }
                else{
                        $FArray[$MesI]=$result[$i];

                    }
            }

            echo "<pre>",var_dump($FArray),"</pre>";
```

Me la muestra asi.

```
     array(1) {
     [5]=>
     array(9) {
        [0]=>string(3) "131"
        [1]=> string(10) "2017-05-24"
        [2]=>string(10) "2017-06-24"
        [3]=>string(1) "A"
        [4]=>string(1) "B"
        [5]=>string(1) "1"
        [6]=>string(1) "0"
        [7]=>string(1) "1"
        [8]=>array(8) {
           [0]=>string(3) "132"
           [1]=>string(10) "2017-05-24"
           [2]=>string(10) "2017-06-10"
           [3]=>string(1) "C"
           [4]=>string(1) "D"
           [5]=>string(1) "0"
           [6]=>string(1) "1"
           [7]=> string(1) "0"
   }
  }
 }
```

Pero quiero que me la muestre asi.

```
     array(1) {
     [5]=>array(2){
        [0]=>array(8) {
         [0]=>string(3) "131"
         [1]=> string(10) "2017-05-24"
         [2]=>string(10) "2017-06-24"
         [3]=>string(1) "A"
         [4]=>string(1) "B"
         [5]=>string(1) "1"
         [6]=>string(1) "0"
         [7]=>string(1) "1"
          }
         [1]=>array(8) {
           [0]=>string(3) "132"
           [1]=>string(10) "2017-05-24"
           [2]=>string(10) "2017-06-10"
           [3]=>string(1) "C"
           [4]=>string(1) "D"
           [5]=>string(1) "0"
           [6]=>string(1) "1"
           [7]=> string(1) "0"
           }
  }
 }
```

Ejemplo para explicarlo mejor.

Aqui la array multi con los datos y la fechas  que son del mes 5 y 6.

```
$result=[
            array("131","2017-05-24","2017-06-24","A","B","1","0","1"),
            array("132","2017-06-24","2017-06-10","C","D","0","1","0"),
            ];
```

Aqui la array como quiero que quede.

```
         $FArry=[
      /*aqui index 5 que hace referencia mes de Mayo*/   
               [5] => [0]=>array("131","2017-05-24","2017-06-24","A","B","1","0","1"),

    /*aqui index 6 que hace referencia mes de Junio*/
               [6]=>  [0]=>array("132","2017-06-1","2017-06-10","C","D","0","1","0"),
            ]
```

No si esta vez me explicado mejor.

Comment: Lo leí tres veces y no entendí lo que querías hacer.

Comment: Perdon, voy a editar para explicarlo mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu planteamiento es correcto, salvo por un detalle, `$FArray` es un "array de arrays", sin embargo, cuando lo inicializas la primera vez (si el índice no existe) lo haces igualándolo al array que estás evaluando en lugar de almacenar este array en la primera posición del array. Es fácil de solucionar

```
<?php 

        $result=[
            array("131","2017-05-24","2017-06-24","A","B","1","0","1"),
            array("132","2017-05-24","2017-06-10","C","D","0","1","0"),
            ];

$FArray=[];

            for ($i=0; $i<count($result);$i++) {

                $NIMes=substr($result[$i][1],-5,5);
                $MesIN=substr($NIMes,1,2);
                $FIMes=substr($result[$i][2],-5,5);
                $MesFI=substr($FIMes,0,2);
                $MesI=(int)$MesIN;
                $MesF=(int)$MesFI;


                if (array_key_exists($MesI,$FArray)) {
                    array_push($FArray[$MesI],$result[$i]);
                }else{
                        $FArray[$MesI][] = $result[$i];

                    }
            }

            echo "<pre>",var_dump($FArray),"</pre>";
```

Observa la diferencia:

```
$FArray[$MesI][] = $result[$i];
```

En lugar de:

```
$FArray[$MesI] = $result[$i];
```

Comment: no me di cuenta, me faltaba eso,fallo mio, gracias ya me funciona y  muestra las arrays como yo quiero.